# convert ruby String to Bignum

Tags: ruby, bignum

I have a binary string, say

```
x = "c1\x98\xCCf3\x1C\x00.\x01\xC7\x00\xC0"
```

(actually much longer).  I need to have it represented as Bignum, for the purposes of further conversion to base-something sequences (something > 36).

```
x.unpack('H*')[0].to_i
```

yields an Integer from first bytes of the value, and not a Bignum.

Comment: In Ruby, the type Integer encompasses Fixnums and Bignums.  Why do you say it is not a Bignum?  I get `Bignum` when I say `x.unpack('H*')[0].to_i.class` where `x` is very large.

Comment: @Ray: You must be getting lucky and not hitting any non-decimal digits until you get far enough along for a Bignum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to use `unpack` and go through an intermediate hex string representation.

To convert a binary string directly to a number (which will automatically be a Bignum as needed), you can do:

```
"\xc1\x98\xCC\xf3\x1C\x00".bytes.inject {|a, b| (a << 8) + b }
 => 212862017674240
```

Answer (score 6):

The default base for [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-to_i) is, of course, 10 but you're trying to convert hex so you want `.to_i(16)`. If you don't specify the base, `to_i` will stop when it sees the first non-decimal value and that's where your truncation comes from.

You want to say this:

```
x.unpack('H*')[0].to_i(16)
```

For example:

```
>> "633198cc66331c0001c700c0633198cc66331c0001c700c063312e98cc66331c0001c700c0".to_i
=> 633198
>> "633198cc66331c0001c700c0633198cc66331c0001c700c063312e98cc66331c0001c700c0".to_i(16)
=> 49331350698902676183344474146684368690988113012187221237314170009285390086987127695278272
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tested this, and at least in 2.5.0 this option is *much* faster.